# Filter issue with tire elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

```
Want to search for the title from the board with live_flag true.

class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :deals
   include Tire::Model::Search

  tire.mapping do
    indexes :title,  type: 'string'
    indexes :deals do
      indexes :title, type: 'string'
    end
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    {
    :title          => title,
    :deals     => {:title => self.deals.map(&:title)},
    }.to_json
  end

  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true) do
      query  {string params[:query]+"*"}
      filter :term, live_flag: true
      sort { by :created_at, "desc" } if params[:query].blank?
    end
  end

end



Now it will not search anything.


It works properly when below code is used. Difference is that i have removed filter text from it.

   def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true) do
      query  {string params[:query]+"*"}
      sort { by :created_at, "desc" } if params[:query].blank?
    end
  end

   **But i want to get boards whose live_flag is true.**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now your index does not include the live_flag
just add live_flag to your to_indexed_json and mapping

```
tire.mapping do
    indexes :title,  type: 'string'
    indexes :live_flag, type: 'boolean'
    indexes :deals do
      indexes :title, type: 'string'
    end
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    {
    :title          => title,
    :live_flag     => live_flag,
    :deals     => {:title => self.deals.map(&:title)},
    }.to_json
  end
```

Comment: Now after you've edited your post, it's a fully qualified answer. The first version (with one sentence and no code) `was presented to me for REVIEW by Stack Overflow` as a low quality post. This was my duty and my right to assess your answer. Learn more about how SO works. Do not take comments personally. We all work to improve the quality of questions and answers. The best proof that this approach works is the fact that you have edited your answer and it fulfills SO standards now - for the good of other users.

Comment: I thought you where at the wrong question that's you i said that. sorry anyway.